# ImportError: No module named 'indexer' Flask, Spellchecker

Tags: docker, flask, import, spell-checking

I need to dockerize a flask app that uses `spellchecker`. When running the docker image I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'indexer'

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spellchecker/core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from indexer import DictionaryIndex
ImportError: No module named 'indexer'
```

Answer (score 10):

I was facing same error, I added `pyspellchecker` into `requirements.txt` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please include your Dockerfile to help us provide a more accurate answer.

You will need to reference your `indexer` module probably as input to a `pip install` as part of your Docker build in order that the relevant modules are part of the image so that your code may access them.

A good way to do this is to add any|all modules needed to a `requirements.txt` file and then something similar to `RUN pip install --requirement requirements.txt` as part of your Dockerfile.

Python's definitive repository on DockerHub includes good instructions that should help guide you:

https://hub.docker.com/_/python/#how-to-use-this-image